# when user enter wrong username and password while login it did not flash any error message in ROR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my application, I use the devise for authentication but when the user enters the wrong username and password it just refresh the page but did not flash any error message like "username and password are wrong", however when I entered something wrong in registration form it flashes the relevant message. I tried a lot of things and also made changes but nothing works. So please someone helps me to figure out it. In which files I need to make changes for flashing an error message. Thanks :).

Comment: You need to include the code in question, otherwise, you can't reasonably expect an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line into your application.html.erb file.

```
  <% if notice && alert %>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have taken this code out of your view:    <%= notice %>

If you put it into the application.html.erb file, the better place most of the time, you'll need to remove it from all the other views that still have it, or those pages will show the notice twice.